# What is the most efficient way to map SHA 256 digests to an integer?

Tags: hashmap, hashtable

Say I already have a set of SHA-256 digests and I would like to map each digest to a specific integer. Is there some way to exploit the fact that the key is already a very good hash? Or perhaps that the key is always exactly 256 bits?

Comment: An SHA-256 digest is already an integer written down using base 16. If you want a smaller integer, truncate.

Comment: I would like to map the digest to a specific integer as I would with a hash map.

Comment: @AndreyPortnoy I wasn't thinking clearly. I see now that what you said is correct. Truncate the SHA to some bit-width to allow the resultant unsigned integer range to cover the smaller hash map range. Use this integer as the pointer to my arbitrary integer. Handle collisions.

Comment: @user276833: yeah - it's common for hash functions to return hash values with many more bits than the hash table bucket indices need, and the hash table will bitwise-`&` (mask) or `%` (mod) the hash value to identify a specific bucket.  SHA256 is strong enough to make truncation reasonable; with a non-cryptographic-strength hash value, you could `^` (XOR) several slices of the hash value (e.g. lowest 16 bits with next 16 bits etc. to produce 16 bit hash value), but if the hash table implementation uses a prime number of buckets and '%' you can reasonably skip that; power-of-2 #buckets suck.